# Find value in row header sum corresponding column

Tags: excel-formula

I am seeking to sum values in one column in one sheet based on a value in a second sheet.

- In Sheet A, B3 = "JD".
- In Sheet B, there is a column specifically marked "JD".

I want a formula that will find the column in sheet B that is named the value in B3 (JD), and return the sum for all values in that column.

I know it should be simple but cannot figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
=SUM(INDEX(SheetB!$A:$Z,0,MATCH(B3,SheetB!$1:$1,0)))
```